# IvoryCKEditor and FMElfinder - buttons grayed out

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, elfinder

I've installed and configured both bundles according to the [docs](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/file_browse_upload.md), but when I open the file browser, I can't actually *do* anything.  All but the help buttons are grayed out.  A link to a screenshot: [screenie](http://www.mpphp.com/fmelfinder.JPG)

My upload folder appears to have the correct permissions (664), and no errors are popping up.  Am I using it wrong?  I intend to have my end users to be able to upload images and other files from their systems to the server through the CKEditor.

Comment: Hi, it seems there is some javascript lib crashing. Do you have check this with firebug console if there is any js error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it *was* a permissions issue.  D'oh.  Setting permissions to 777 cleared it right up.